# Xpath expression to get unknown element names with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, expression

Iam trying to write an xpath expression to get element names from an xml based on some criterias.

The thing iam after is to get a list of the element name of each element that has the child node "fields/enable". I don't know what the name of the elements is, i dont have any attribut to trigger by, the element can be any xml acceptable name.

In the example bellow iam interested in the following result:

```
ajob
bjob
cjob
```

I managed to the the label names for each node i was interested in. In this example the label name is exactly the same name as the element name i want but i cant rely on that the label will not the changed. The only sure thing i have is the element name.

```
->xpath("//wrapper/groups/*/fields/enable/../../label");
```

I google on this and got several hits with different combination of the use if name(). I never managed to get any of my attempt to get name() to return any values.

```
->xpath("//wrapper/groups/*/fields//enable/../name(parent::*)");
```

or

```
->xpath("name(//wrapper/groups/*/fields/enable/../..)");
```

I have simplified the XML example below but the basic structure and the element of interest is still there

I would be thankful for any help i can get.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <wrapper>
      <groups>
         <ainfo>
            <label>Information</label>
         </ainfo>
         <atimer>
            <label>Schedule</label>
            <fields>
               <time />
               <frequency />
            </fields>
         </atimer>
         <ajob>
            <label>ajob</label>
            <fields>
               <enable>1</enable>
            </fields>
         </ajob>
         <btimer>
            <label>Schedule</label>
            <fields>
               <time />
               <frequency />
            </fields>
         </btimer>
         <bjob>
            <label>bjob</label>
            <fields>
               <enable>1</enable>
            </fields>
         </bjob>
         <cinfo>
            <label>Information</label>
         </cinfo>
         <cjob>
            <label>cjob</label>
            <fields>
               <enable>1</enable>
            </fields>
         </cjob>
      </groups>
   </wrapper>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT below should give you what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[fields/enable=1]">      
      <xsl:value-of select="name(current())" />      
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it live: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/JYfpsX/3

You can use the xpath to retrieve a set of nodes which you can then loop in PHP and retrieve the name of the node in each iteration. The PHP DOMNode class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) has a property called 'nodeName'.

Answer (score 1):

For the given XML [here's a working solution](http://codepad.org/Zm9uSgiH) using PHP, SimpleXML and a minor change to the `//wrapper/groups/*/fields/enable/../../label` XPath expression you provided:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <wrapper>
      <groups>
         <ainfo>
            <label>Information</label>
         </ainfo>
         <atimer>
            <label>Schedule</label>
            <fields>
               <time />
               <frequency />
            </fields>
         </atimer>
         <ajob>
            <label>ajob</label>
            <fields>
               <enable>1</enable>
            </fields>
         </ajob>
         <btimer>
            <label>Schedule</label>
            <fields>
               <time />
               <frequency />
            </fields>
         </btimer>
         <bjob>
            <label>bjob</label>
            <fields>
               <enable>1</enable>
            </fields>
         </bjob>
         <cinfo>
            <label>Information</label>
         </cinfo>
         <cjob>
            <label>cjob</label>
            <fields>
               <enable>1</enable>
            </fields>
         </cjob>
      </groups>
   </wrapper>
</config>
XML;

$sxe           = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$enabledLabels = $sxe->xpath('//wrapper/groups/*/fields/enable[.=1]/../../label');

foreach ($enabledLabels as $enabledLabel) {
    echo "$enabledLabel\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
ajob
bjob
cjob
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando ! In my program the xsd file will be given using that find all node names and the parent node of each node to be printed.It's must in dynamic coding.? Any idea to make this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865892/how-to-retrieve-node-number-based-on-parent-node-dynamically-from-xsd-file-using

Comment: I advise you to open a new question with as much detail as possible to get a better answer to your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$element = $sxe->xpath("//wrapper/groups//fields[enable=1]/../label");

foreach($element as $node)
{
  echo $node,"<br/>";
}
```